# Proof with stationary distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

> Let $\pi(k)$ the stationary distribution of the Markov Chain. Show
>   that if $$p_{ij}^{(n)}\geq\varepsilon$$ for some $i,j,n,\varepsilon$
>   then $$\pi(j)\geq \varepsilon \pi(i)$$

I'm litle lost here
$$\pi(j)=\sum_i p(i,j)\pi(i)$$
$$p_{ij}^{(n)}\rightarrow \pi(j)$$
thus
$$p_{ij}^{(n)}\rightarrow \pi(j)\Rightarrow \pi(j)\geq\varepsilon$$

but do not know how to proceed and check the relationship

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\pi(j)=\sum_i p^{(2)}(i,j)\pi(i)$.  And then the same with 2 replaced by 3, etc.